# Tridion 2013 SP1 CMS UI feature regression

Tags: 2013, publishing, cme, 2013-sp1

We recently upgraded from Tridion 2011 to 2013 SP1. I remembering being able to see the error message for publishing/deployment failures in the publishing window (on Tridion 2011). For example "Attempting to deploy a binary XXXXX to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: XXXXX" but seems like that's not possible on Tridion 2013 SP1. In Tridion 2013 SP1, the error message details are not displayed [please attached screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxYOm.png). In order to troubleshoot publishing or deployment failures, we now have to look at deployer or tridion core logs which is not end-user friendly. We raised a support ticket with SDL support and got the following unhelpful response:

*"Unfortunately this wouldn't be something we would consider as a defect unless the product is not functioning as designed. In the example provided this doesn't appear to be the case.
If you do feel there is a product defect here then it would help to see screenshots of the issue. Then we can validate these against what the designed behavior is.
Also with regard to submitting enhancement requests through support, the procedure has only recently changed. Now all requests go via the ideas site, even ones submitted to support."*

**Tridion-product experts**: Do you know why this user-friendly error message feature got removed in the Tridion 2013 SP1 release, and is creating this as an "idea" the only way to get the feature back?

Comment: I submitted an answer on the question. If you don't agree with Support, consider following up with Support or SDL directly. Having worked with Support before as a customer myself and now as a colleague, it just feels awkward seeing a Support response pasted and cited as unhelpful.

Comment: Well, "the unhelpful" comment is for the overall experience and not necessarily based on that specific response. I believe that they resolved the case with the above explanation. The other challenge we have is that our vendor creates support tickets on our behalf and we would have to request our vendor to reopen the ticket or create a new ticket etc. Anyway, I'd have expected them to provide better or alternative solutions (for UI error reporting)if they have been replaced in the latest version of the product. (shows customer focus)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tridion Support and their opinion/dislike of a feature that was changed.

Comment: This question is not off topic. My original question to the forum was if anyone had noticed that publish transaction error details were no longer being reported in the GUI (on 2013 SP1) and if there were any plans to address that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hotfix for the error message that you mentioned (CD_2013.1.0.88163). I don't know what the new message is, but hopefully it provides the details you are looking for.

I'm not convinced there's actually a problem with the UI. The dialog supports showing details, but they have to have been provided by the source raising the error.

As mentioned, though, we are always looking to improve our products so feel free to provide your feedback through the proper channels (in case this isn't isolated to the error addressed by the hotfix)

Comment: Thank you for this information. We will try installing this hotfix and see if includes the level of detail we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question:

- No, I'm not sure why it was changed. But if there was an answer, it won't fix your real concern to get the previous error message back.
- Ideas isn't the only way to request the feature, you can still follow up with Support with the screenshot. The product doesn't always follow precedents, but past behavior can sometimes help.

I've seen and been confused by the difference in the error messages between versions. I also agree with Support's response, which includes both the Ideas option but also the opportunity to follow up with the screenshot.

I'd recommend:

- Point out the difference between versions
- Submit the [Ideas](http://ideas.sdltridion.com) and mention it or link to it here so others can vote on it

I might be particular, but the previous message wasn't *quite* directed at CMS editors, though. If you post the request on Ideas, I might comment to ask for further instructions for the user. :-)